# Addition and Multiplication Independent of Permutations

Tags: analysis, natural-numbers

Note: In this discussion, $0$ is included in $\mathbb{N}$.

In Chapter 1, Section 5.13 (a) from Analysis I by Amann and Escher, there is the following statement:

> ...
>
> If addition $+$ and multiplication $\cdot$ are commutative, we have
>
> $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}x_{\sigma{(j)}}$ and $\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}=\prod_{j=0}^{n}x_{\sigma{(j)}}$
>
> for any permutation $\sigma$ of the numbers $0,\cdots ,n$, that is, for any bijective function $\sigma :\{0,\cdots ,n\}\to\{0,\cdots ,n\}$.

This was stated without proof. However, it does not appear to be that obvious to me at least.

Before this statement, it has previously been proved that if $\odot$ is an associative operation on a set $X$, the value of any valid expression involving $\odot$, elements of $X$ and parentheses, is independent of the placement of parentheses.

In addition, for an associative operation on some set $X$ and with $x_{k}\in X$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, it is possible to give a recursive definition for the expression:

$\displaystyle\bigodot_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}$

This is achieved by the following definitions:

$\displaystyle\bigodot_{k=0}^{0}x_{k}=x_{0}$

$\displaystyle\bigodot_{k=0}^{n+1}x_{k}=\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}\right)\odot x_{n+1}$

My idea is to prove the original statement is to deal with a more general case where $\odot$ is both an associative and a commutative operation on $X$.

This is proved by induction on $n$. For $n=1$, $x_{0}\odot x_{1}=x_{1}\odot x_{0}$ because $\odot$ is a commutative operation, and this covers all permutations of $\{0,1\}$.

Now suppose that this property holds for some $n\geq 1$ and let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $\{0,\cdots ,n+1\}$. Then there exists some unique $\ell\in\{0,\cdots ,n+1\}$ such that $\sigma{(\ell)}=n+1$.

If $\ell\in\mathbb{N}^{\times}$ where $\mathbb{N}^{\times}$ is defined as $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, $\ell =\ell^{'}+1$ for some $\ell^{'}\in\mathbb{N}$.

In addition, letting $\sigma^{'}$ be defined by $\sigma^{'}(k)=\sigma{(k)}$ for $0\leq k<\ell$ and $\sigma^{'}(k)=\sigma{(k+1)}$ for $\ell\leq k\leq n$ defines a permutation on $\{0,\cdots ,n\}$.

Then expanding the following expression from definition:

$\displaystyle\bigodot_{k=0}^{n+1}x_{\sigma{(k)}}=\left(\cdots\left(\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{\ell^{'}}x_{\sigma{(k)}}\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(\ell)}}\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(n+1)}}$

Applying that $\odot$ is a commutative operation and that $\bigodot_{k=0}^{\ell^{'}}x_{\sigma{(k)}}$ is in $X$:

$\displaystyle =\left(\cdots\left(x_{\sigma{(\ell)}}\odot\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{\ell^{'}}x_{\sigma{(k)}}\right)\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(n+1)}}$

As this is a valid expression involving elements of $X$, parentheses and an associative operation $\odot$, the order of the brackets can be changed without affecting the value:

$\displaystyle =x_{\sigma{(\ell)}}\odot\left(\left(\cdots\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{\ell^{'}}x_{\sigma{(k)}}\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(n+1)}}\right)$

Again applying that $\odot$ is commutative:

$\displaystyle =\left(\left(\cdots\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{\ell^{'}}x_{\sigma{(k)}}\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(n+1)}}\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(\ell)}}$

Replacing the terms with $\sigma{(k)}$ in terms of their corresponding expression with $\sigma^{'}$ combined with applying that $\sigma{(\ell)}=n+1$:

$\displaystyle =\left(\left(\cdots\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{\ell^{'}}x_{\sigma^{'}{(k)}}\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma^{'}{(n)}}\right)\odot x_{n+1}$

Applying the definition of $\bigodot$:

$\displaystyle =\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{n}x_{\sigma^{'}{(k)}}\right)\odot x_{n+1}$

Applying the induction hypothesis and using the definition of $\bigodot$ again:

$\displaystyle =\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}\right)\odot x_{n+1}=\bigodot_{k=0}^{n+1}x_{k}$

This deals with the case $\ell\in\mathbb{N}^{\times}$. If $\ell =0$, giving $\sigma^{'}$ the same definition as above, the chain of equalities with the same justification as above give:

$\displaystyle\bigodot_{k=0}^{n+1}x_{\sigma{(k)}}=\left(\cdots\left(x_{\sigma{(0)}}\odot x_{\sigma{(1)}}\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(n+1)}}$

$=x_{\sigma{(0)}}\odot\left(\left(\cdots\left(x_{\sigma{(1)}}\odot x_{\sigma{(2)}}\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(n+1)}}\right)$

$=\left(\left(\cdots\left(x_{\sigma{(1)}}\odot x_{\sigma{(2)}}\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(n+1)}}\right)\odot x_{\sigma{(0)}}$

$=\left(\left(\cdots\left(x_{\sigma^{'}{(0)}}\odot x_{\sigma^{'}{(1)}}\right)\odot\cdots\right)\odot x_{\sigma^{'}{(n)}}\right)\odot x_{n+1}$

$\displaystyle =\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{n}x_{\sigma^{'}{(k)}}\right)\odot x_{n+1}=\left(\bigodot_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}\right)\odot x_{n+1}=\bigodot_{k=0}^{n+1}x_{k}$

I was wondering, as no proof was given, if there is a shorter argument that gives the result above?

Comment: I think that there is no other way to give a proper proof. Most people just wave their hands and say "obvious".

Comment: Use induction, it’s tedious but not hard.

Comment: @ancientmathematician What do you mean? Using induction is the only way to solve these problems since the *definition* of a sum/product is *inductive (or as some people prefer recursive*).

Comment: It may be a bit cleaner and easier to read to take advantage of the fact that every permutation can be written as a product of transpositions of consecutive elements, and that transpositions here in this context is the basic commutativity property involving only two elements.  For instance how $a+b+c+d = a+(c+b)+d = (c+a)+b+d = c+a+(d+b)$.  A sketch of a proof would be to show that given some sum where the indices of the sum are according to some permutation, this is equal to the sum where the indices are same apart from two adjacent terms being swapped.

Comment: That is, $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_{\sigma(i)} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} a_{\sigma(i)} + a_{\sigma(k)} + a_{\sigma(k+1)} + \sum\limits_{i=k+2}^n a_{\sigma(i)} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} a_{\sigma(i)} + a_{\sigma(k+1)} + a_{\sigma(k)} + \sum\limits_{i=k+2}^n a_{\sigma(i)} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_{(\sigma\circ\tau_k)(i)}$ where $\tau_k$ is the transposition swapping $k$ with $k+1$

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the helpful comments or suggestions.